# How to call a custom sql package from a jsp page/java program

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jsp, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a sql package which has many queries inside(select/create/insert etc). From a jsp page, I need to invoke the sql package but I do not know how to call that package. I tried by stating single query explicity and that worked but I do not know how to run the entire scripts inside the package.
Thanks in advance

Comment: put your queries in a stored procedure and execute that using JDBC

Comment: @Sanjeev should i execute the procedure by writing the following:       public static final String SOME_NAME = "{call   schema_name.org_name_pkg.procedure_name}"

Comment: Can you show how you call your query at the jsp page?

Comment: @CarlitosWay :  String name = request.getParameter("myText");

 String selectSQL = "select * from INTERFACE_RUN where TO_CHAR(INTERFACE_RUN.START_TIME,'DD-MON-YY')='"+name+"'";
 System.out.println("1");
    
 try{
         Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); 
       
         Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
         "jdbc:oracle:thin:@abc:1521:xyz", "uname", "pw");
       

      PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(selectSQL) ;
   
      ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery();

Comment: @CarlitosWay I need to execute the whole package and not any single procedure inside the package

Comment: So, You need to call ALL the public functions and procedures that a PL/SQL package has?? Why do you need that? Do you know how the package is composed?? Do you need to execute the package methods at some specific order?? What about parameters (IN or OUT) ??

Comment: Use CallableStatement to call procedures

Comment: @CarlitosWay : There is only one IN parameter which is a date input. I am sorry, I just need to run one procedure from the PL/SQL package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a small adaptation of your example:

```
String date = request.getParameter("myDate");
String expr = "call my_package.my_proc(TO_DATE(?, 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI:SS')";
try{
  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
  Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@abc:1521:xyz", "uname", "pw");
  CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall(expr);
  statement.setString(1, date)
  statement.execute();
}
```

Comment: Thank you @CarlitosWay- how does one get input from the user in date format? I need to pass that as an argument in my procedure call

Comment: It failed at the statement.execute(); line. My code was the following:

Comment: String date = request.getParameter("myText");
 String selectSQL = "{call PK_ISR_ADV.scheduler_adv(TO_CHAR(?,'DD-MON-YYYY'))}";
    
 try{
         Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); 

         Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
         "jdbc:oracle:thin:@abc:1521:xyz", "uname", "pw");

         CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall(selectSQL);
    
    statement.setString(1, date);
    
    statement.execute();

Comment: the argument to the procedure 'scheduler_adv' is of DATE datatype. I guess thats why its failing since we are passing Char

Comment: Yes, that is why you have to use the TO_DATE (no TO_CHAR) function that I suggested to you...

Comment: it is still failing at the statement.execute() line

Comment: What about the stacktrace (Put it as an udpate to your question)... not comments...

Comment: There is no stacktrace. It compiles but it is not able to resolve the 'call 'query and execute it. It therefore goes into the catch part of it and prints error as the message since I have mentioned system.out.println("error")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114667/discussion-between-carlitos-way-and-aniket).

Comment: Thanks - Solved by not putting the TO_CHAR expression